# Recursive C function

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I need to write a recursive function in C which would, for a certain n, calculate the number of n-bit binary numbers that don't have three consecutive digits 1..

For an example, for n=3, all possible 3-bit numbers are: 
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111

so the function returns 7 because there's only one number with three 1s.

So far, I don't even know where to start. I can't see any algorithm that could help me.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure we're supposed to do your homework for you...

Comment: @Myst I still think it is a good question (even though it might be the homework). The algorithm part here is more interesting than the C implementation.

Comment: Did you consider why the assignment suggested a recursive solution? maybe this is a hint for the algorithm you should design.

Comment: Start by writing it as a loop. And once you've got that working, forget about recursion and keep the loop. Recursion is one of those really dumb, really bad practice things, that people spend far too much time pondering about.

Comment: @AlexLop. I'm not sure a question should be up-voted because a teacher gave an interesting assignment (rather then a boring one).

Comment: @Lundin Hey, you might be (somewhat) right about C and imperative languages, but functional programming is built on recursion. And even in imperative languages there are recursive data structures that are naturally handled with recursion.

Comment: @Lundin - some algorithms are very simple to write when using recursion and very difficult to write when using a loop (consider tree traversal as an example). I'm not saying this is the case here, but it might be.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is tagged C. I couldn't care less about functional programming languages. That being said, I know of no existing computer that implements recursion in a good way. No programming language in the world can save you from all the severe disadvantages that come with recursion, if the CPU itself will stack every recursive function call.

Comment: First question to ask, if  `n > 3` will four in a row count as well (since the first 3 are consecutive) or will it be kept as "not 3 consecutive"? For example what will `1111` be treated as. The answer to that will affect the algorithm you consider.

Comment: @Lundin Even if it is not good practice, he is required to use recursion for this. Saying to ignore the requirement is not a valid answer.

Comment: @Myst That's mostly a myth. If you write your tree so that every node in the tree has a parent pointer, there is no need to use recursion. So recursion for tree traversal ends up as a (pre-mature) optimization to save a tiny bit of data memory, at the expanse of execution time and stack usage. I would imagine that there are very few systems that needs such a strange optimization. The norm is to optimize for speed.

Comment: @sabbahillel On the contrary: to question the requirements is what separates the engineers from the code monkeys.

Comment: @Lundin Can you write DFS algorithm right away using iteration? I doubt it. Well, if you can then you probably have some experience with it. Then think of red-black trees and oher graph theory, or sorting. You have to start with recursion and then to use techniques to unwrap it. This is a very least of a reason to understand recursion

Comment: @Lundin Question yes, ignore no. In this case the answer to the question is that the "customer" needs to have recursion used for the "product" In this case to teach the student how to use recursion if it is needed. Consider the rquirement to use a less than optimal library because that is the only one the customer has a license for.as an example.

Comment: @sabbahillel It would count as 3 consecutive..
And to all of you guys, it is not my homework, it is just a task from last-year test that was written on my college and since I'm studying for this-year's test, I was hoping that you may help me.
No need for a full code, just a hint or anything would be helpful..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Just because recursion is helpful in algorithm theory, doesn't mean that it should be used in the real world, where there are computers. I believe various computer scientists have proven that every case of recursion can be unrolled. Recursion unrolling may of course lead to _less readable code_, but it can never lead to slower or less unsafe code. At any rate, recursion is not something you should touch before you are working with algorithm theory. Teaching beginner programmers recursion is harmful - they will end up using it to solve trivial problems. Like in this question.

Comment: in an 8 bit number, how many possible numbers exist? (2^n including 0) How many permutations exist where three consecutive bits exist? (`0b111`, `0b1110`, `0b11100`...)... subtract one from the other...?

Comment: @sabbahillel A clever student would rather question: why are you teaching us recursion for? This is a beginner class in C, we have not yet studied algorithm theory. In fact, the student might not ever study algorithm theory, in which case they will never need to know about recursion either.

Comment: In that case, an immediate true (the first 3 found) would kick you ou with the result.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no MCVE was provided.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It isn't a question about a problem in code so none is needed. As long as there is no explicit code begging, the question isn't off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's construct our number that doesn't have three consecutive ones from left to right.

It necessarily starts with at most two 1s, so it starts with either no 1s, a single 1, or two 1s. In other words, our number starts with either 0, 10 or 110. In all of these cases, the only restriction for the remainder of the number is that it doesn't contain any three consecutive ones, so this allows us to apply the same function recursively:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

uint64_t nothreeconsecutive(int n) {
    if (n <= 2) return 1 << n;
    return nothreeconsecutive(n-1) + nothreeconsecutive(n-2) + nothreeconsecutive(n-3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by observing that the number of n-bit binary numbers that *don't* include three adjacent set bits is `pow(2, n)` minus the number of n-bit numbers *with* three adjacent set bits.

Furthermore, the number of binary numbers of length `n` with three adjacent bits set is twice that of such numbers of length `n-1` (both values of the last bit lead to a number with three adjacent bits set), plus the number of binary numbers of length `n-1` with the initial two bits set (for the case where the new bit is set), minus those numbers of length `n-1` and the two initial bits set that already had three adjacent bits set before (as they are already counted once).

Thus, after changing the return types a bit to enable longer sequences to be calculated, a solution to the problem could look like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

uint64_t twoadjstart(int a)
{
  /*returns the number of binary numbers with a bits that have no more than 2 adjacent initial set bits.*/
  if (a < 2)
    return 0;
  if (a == 2)
    return 1;
  return UINT64_C(1) << (a - 3);
}

uint64_t recuadjthree(int a)
{
/*returns the number of binary numbers with a bits that do contain three adjacent set bits.*/
  if (a < 3)
    return 0;
  uint64_t retval = 2*recuadjthree(a-1);
  retval += twoadjstart(a-1);
  retval -= recuadjthree(a-4);
  return retval;
}

uint64_t recunothree(int a)
{
  /*returns the number of binary numbers with a bits that do not contain three adjacent set bits.*/
  uint64_t combi = UINT64_C(1) << a;
  return combi - recuadjthree(a);
}
```

Comment: It's much easier to count the ones that don't have three consecutive ones. They either start with 0, 10 or 110, so f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-3)

Comment: @ffao: That's a very clever way of putting it. Unfortunately, it's also *vastly* slower (compiled with `gcc -O3`, a factor of ~4500 for n==32) probably due to the more branchy recursion. Nice though.

Comment: Well, discussing efficiency in this problem doesn't make a lot of sense in the first place because there are far more efficient ways of doing it than either of these solutions (log n * M, where M is for multiplying large integers). So I shot for clarity instead...

Comment: @ffao: Yeah, after memoizing and going bottom-up rather than top-down, the difference shrinks to 1:2 or so... in favor of your solution. Post an answer, get an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

Think about the numbers as strings of bits, so the questions comes to how to find a substring `111`. The good thing about bits is you can do bit shifts on it, and try to mask the lower three bit out, and compare whether it is `111`. Try this:

```
bool valid(int n) {
    while (n) {
        if ((n & 0x7) == 7)
             return false;
        n = n >> 1;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Second, think about how to get all the n-bits numbers. You can easily note that those numbers are from all 0's to all 1's, so that you can make a loop to loop through all these numbers, and check each number with the function in the first step.

Now you have an iterative solution, think about how you can implement the same thing as recursion.

Comment: Not a fully correct solution... for example: n=7 you have also **1110111**, 1110000, 0000111, 0001110, 0011100, 0111000

Comment: If it is a signed number, shifting may keep the sign bit set (or not). If that case, you may get an infinite loop.

Comment: @sabbahillel If it's negative the result is implementation defined, the `valid` function should accept inputs of range 0 to INT_MAX. Or make the parameter unsigned type.

Comment: Isn't the answer `pow(2.0, (double)n) - (n-2 > 0 ? n-2 : 0)`?

Comment: @Myst Great! That's is the mathematical way. Why are you make it a comment, make an answer! :)

Answer (score -1):

The following is a **wrong** (partial) solution (as pointed to by @EOF).

I'm leaving the wrong solution so the comments will make sense and for the person looking for the correct solution to learn from my mistakes.

**the mistake**: This solution only relates to an `n` bit number with the last 3 bits set to `1` and ignores the possibility that the the `1` bits will be in the middle of the number.

**maybe**: completing this solution will require us to subtract (again and again the solution for `n-1` (until n == 0) from the solution to `n`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define pow2(n) ipow(2,n);

int solution(int n)
{
   if(n <= 2)
     return pow2(n);
   return pow2(n) - pow2(n-3);
   // The return statement, after the `if`, should probably have been:
   return pow2(n) - pow2(n-3) - solution(n-1);
}

int main()
{
   int n = 7;
   printf("The solution for n = %d is %d", n, solution(n));
}
```

My Logic:

If there are `n` bits, then the number of possible numbers (including 0) is 2^n (2 in the power of n).

In an n bit number, there are n-2 ways to fit three consecutive set bits (`0b111`, `0b1110`, `0b11100`)... this is IF n > 2.

As pointed to in the comments, each of these numbers has non 0 bit possibilities (i.e. `0b11101` as well as `0b11100`).

So:

- For n = 3, we have 0 remaining bit (1 possible numbers == 2^0)
- For n = 4, we have 1 remaining bit (2 possible numbers == 2^1)
- For n = 5, we have 2 remaining bits, either separated or together (4 possible solutions == 2^2).

etc...

These possibilities are 2 in the power of the remaining bits (n-3).

... I doubt the placement of the bits is important, what we know is that we have 2^n permutations for all possible numbers and that if three bits are the same then we have 2^(n-3) permutations of numbers.

Thank you to KlasLindbäck and EOF for their pointers.

Comment: Given n=8 (an 8 bit number), your algorithm gives 250. Surely that cannot be correct, as we have 0xF0, 0xF1, 0xF2...

Comment: You are missing all numbers that contain `111` where not all other bits are `0`.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I missed!

Comment: @KlasLindbäck - I wonder if using `2**(n-2)` will solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(n-2)*2**(n-2)` because the triplet can start in `n-2` places and the other bits can have `2**(n-2)` states for each of them.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck - Does the placement of the bits effect the math for the permutation count? Wouldn't we get duplicates if we consider placement (i.e., all bits are set for n == 7)? When we say that there are 2**(n-2) permutations of numbers with three consecutive bits, aren't we ignoring the question of where these consecutive bits are? Maybe we should use (2**n-3)+1 for the permutation count? Ahhh... I'm lost!

Comment: You are right, it isn't that simple. I think I recognize this problem and I'm fairly certain I've seen a mathematical solution on SO (maybe n was fixed at 8 in that question, I don't remember).

Comment: There are `ipow(2,3) == 8` 3-bit combinations. `ipow(2,3) - ipow(2,1) == 6`, however, only one combination has three adjacent ones, so the solution for `n == 3` should be `7`.

Comment: @EOF, yap, you're right, I locked in two bits instead of three (it should be `n-3`...

Comment: There are `ipow(2,4) == 16` 4-bit combinations. `ipow(2,4) - ipow(2,1) == 14`, however, three combinations (`0111/1110/1111`) have three adjacent ones, so the solution for `n == 4` should be `13`.

Comment: @EOF, I edited the answer, leaving the wrong solution in and explaining the mistake. I hope this one is better. Either way, I'm thankful for your comments.

Comment: Recursively calling `solution(n)` **within** `solution(n)` **itself** is infinite descent. Your new proposal will not even terminate for `n > 2`, much less produce correct results.

Comment: @EOF I'm not sure why you're ignoring the `if` statement at the beginning of the function, I can only blame it on my comment being not clear enough and my unusual formatting (I rely on my IDE to format the if statements using new lines)....

Comment: @EOF Oh.. My bad, I forgot to write the `-1` :-o ... I'm sorry.